# improve startup times of matlab executable

Tags: matlab, executable

I have compiled a matlab standalone exe which I can run on any computer that has the MATLAB Compiler Runtime installed.

However starting the exe takes 20-30 seconds !

How can I measure the time accuratly and most important - how can I decrease it down to 1-2 seconds.

Comment: I don't think you can. But I would definitely like to see a different answer..

Comment: The start-up time is (in my experience) associated with initiating the MCR. I've looked at this problem before and never came up with a way to speed it up (really annoying I agree). However, one point of note: If you call several standalone exe's in a row, the start-up time is (again in my experience) must less from the second call onwards. Probably something to do with the computer being clever enough to hold an initialized MCR in the RAM.

Comment: Do you mean it is slow the first time after deployment/reboot, or every time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is taken out of [Yair Altman's blog](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/):

A splash wrapper application can alleviates much of the pain of the slow startup of deployed (compiled) Matlab applications. [A Splash window solution can be found here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/splash-window-for-deployed-applications/). While such a splash wrapper is indeed useful, it may also be possible to achieve an actual speedup of the compiled app’s startup using the MCR_CACHE_ROOT environment variable.

Normally, the MCR and the stand-alone executable is unpacked upon every startup in the user’s temp dir, and deleted when the user logs out. Apparently, when the MCR_CACHE_ROOT environment variable is set, these files are only unpacked once and kept for later reuse. If this report is indeed true, this could significantly speed up the startup time of a compiled application in subsequent invocations.

On Linux:

```
export MCR_CACHE_ROOT=/tmp/mcr_cache_root_$USER   # local to host
mkdir -p @MCR_CACHE_ROOT
./myExecutable
```

On Windows:

```
REM set MCR_CACHE_ROOT=%TEMP%
set MCR_CACHE_ROOT="C:\Documents and Settings\Yair\Matlab Cache\"
myExecutable.exe
```

There are also ways to set this env variable permanently on Windows if needed...

Setting MCR_CACHE_ROOT is especially important when running the executable from a network (NFS) location, since unpacking onto a network location could be quite slow. If the executable is run in parallel on different machines (for example, a computer cluster running a parallel program), then this might even [cause lock-outs](http://bioinfo.ittc.ku.edu/faq.php?type=11#47) when different clusters try to access the same network location. In both cases, the solution is to set MCR_CACHE_ROOT to a local folder (e.g., /tmp or %TEMP%). If you plan to reuse the extracted files again, then perhaps you should not delete the extracted files but reuse them. Otherwise, simply delete the temporary folder after the executable ends. In the following example, $RANDOM is a bash function that returns a random number:

```
export MCR_CACHE_ROOT=/tmp/mcr$RANDOM
./matlab_executable
rm -rf $MCR_CACHE_ROOT
```

Setting MCR_CACHE_ROOT can also be used to solve other performance bottlenecks in deployed applications, as explained in a [MathWorks technical solution](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-7RH0IV/) and a related article [here](http://matlab4compbio.blogspot.co.il/2010/04/how-to-solve-mcr-cache-access-problems.html).

In a related matter, compiled Matlab executable may fail with a Could not access the MCR component cache error, when Matlab cannot write in the MCR cache directory due to missing permission rights. This can be avoided by setting MCR_CACHE_ROOT to [a non-existent directory](http://wiki.rcs.manchester.ac.uk/community/MatlabWithCondor#MCR_CACHE_ROOT), or to a folder in which there is global access permissions (/tmp or %TEMP% are usually such writable folders) – see related posts [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/283432) and [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/255547).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using deploytool to compile your code, under Project - Settings-Toolboxes on path uncheck any toolboxes that aren't needed by your executable.  I recently had this issue and the above steps cut the executable file size in half and significantly reduced the start time of the executable.